# SharePoint perspectives, 2023

Tags: untagged

I saw Jeff Teper's interview from 1 Dec 2022
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X8A4EIjYWK4

Few times a week I check MS Update Center:
https://admin.microsoft.com/AdminPortal/Home#/MessageCenter and I don't see much records related with 'SharePoint', there were a lot more. It gives a feeling like SharePoint is not a priority for Microsoft developer team. I also remember there were 'SharePoint Community Saturdays' on youtube or something. Now it is closed

Now I see Microsoft Loop - what is this? Looks like Microsoft created a copy of Evernote..
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I3w1enD28XY

What do You think about future of SharePoint? Don't You feel this direction is abandoned, as do I?